# Firebase - Object.key returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to order the query based on multiple values. The problem is, that I can't select the objects key `type` because I get `undefined` when I do so.

```
var filterDataAccordingToDate = function(ref, startTime, endTime, travelType) {

            ref.orderByChild('date')
            .startAt(startTime).endAt(endTime)
            .once('value', function(snapshot) {
                var travel = snapshot.val();

                console.log("TRAVEL OBJ: " + util.inspect(travel, false, null));
                console.log("TRAVEL TYPE: " + travel.type);

                if (travel.type == travelType) {
                    // DO STUFF
                }

            });
    }
```

The first `console.log()` returns the correct object:

```
TRAVEL OBJ: {
  "-KKiZKAVH0-QulKnThhF" : {
    "date" : 1466439009,
    "dest" : 1,
    "fbKey" : "-KKiZKAVH0-QulKnThhF",
    "type" : 1
  }
}
```

The second one: `TRAVEL TYPE: undefined`

Any idea, where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will be retrieving multiple objects you need to iterate over them to get the values for each one.

```
for (var key in travel) {
      console.log("TRAVEL OBJ: " + util.inspect(travel[key], false, null));
      console.log("TRAVEL TYPE: " + travel[key].type);
}
```

Comment: Due to the nature of JavaScript prototypes I recommend using the `snapshot.forEach()` method.

Answer (score 3):

**Use the `.forEach()` method on `DataSnapshot`**

```
snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
  var key = snap.key;
  if (key === travelType) {
    // Do stuff
  }
});
```